# Local jar is not imported correctly in maven jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

**Description**

I have 3 programs.

My main program is named `Main`. Then I have 2 `jar` file : `Utils1` and `Utils2`.

`Utils2` is used in `Utils1`. So I imported it with Maven like below in `Utils1` `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.group.project</groupId> // random text
     <artifactId>Project</artifactId> // random text
     <version>1.0.0</version> // random version
     <scope>system</scope>
     <systemPath>${basedir}/Utils2.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

`Utils2` contains a package named `custompack`, a class named `MyMaths` and a method named `MyAddition`.

`Utils1` contains a class named `CustomMaths` and a method named `CustomAddition`. `CustomAddition` call `Utils2.custompack.MyMaths.MyAddition`.

So the code of `Utils1` looks like :

```
public int CustomAddition (int item1, int item2) {
    MyMaths mymaths = new MyMaths();
    return mymaths.MyAddition(item1, item2);
}
```

**Problem**

I'm facing the below error when I use `CustomAddition` in my `Main` program:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: custompack/MyMaths

**Question**

I suppose that the `Utils2` jar is not imported correctly in `Utils1` jar.

Do you have any idea? Thank you.

Comment: `<systemPath>` is deprecated and should be avoided.

Comment: @JFMeier Thank you for your comment. So, what is your solution? Thanks

Comment: Build Utils2 first with "mvn clean install". Erase the scope and system entry. Then build Utils2.

Comment: Thank you so much it is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

I assume Utils1 and Utils2 both are custom build jar.

Based on how maven works,

- You should build Utils1 project first which should copy the artifact/jar to maven repo(Default is C:\Users[account].m2\repository else check C:\Users[account].m2\settings.xml in case overridden).
- Build Utils2 project and run Main program which makes use of class from Utils2

Also, since these are custom modules, you should add dependency as below -

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.group.project</groupId> // random text
     <artifactId>Utils2</artifactId> // random text
     <version>1.0.0</version> // random version
</dependency>
```

The below should be used when you have a jar not available in maven repo during your build/execution process and needs to be pulled from different location

```
<systemPath>${system_path}/system.jar</systemPath>
```

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! So I do that : <dependency> <groupId>org.group.project</groupId> <artifactId>Utils2</artifactId> <version>1.0.0</version> <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${basedir}/Utils2.jar</systemPath> </dependency> in Utils1 pom.xml. Is it correct?